# Check Screen Saver active in C# fails

Tags: c#, windows-7, screensaver

I try to figure out how to check if the screen saver is active with C# under Windows 7.

Well, I googled this and found some solution all using this:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref bool lpvParam, int flags );
```

And then:

```
private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERACTIVE = 16;
```

Function:

```
public static bool GetScreenSaverActive()
{
     bool isActive = false;

     SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETSCREENSAVERACTIVE, 0, ref isActive, 0);

     return isActive;
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work properly on several PC's.

If the screen saver has never been activated the function `GetScreenSaverActive` returns false. And if the screen saver has been activated it returns true. That´s ok.

But if the screen saver than is de-activated the function returns still true - even if I restart the pc. I have no idea what going on there, but I always get a true when I have activated the screen saver once.

Comment: If only there were [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx#Screensaver) that, say, includes a phrase like "**Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows 2000:**  The function returns **TRUE** even when screen saving is not enabled. For more information and a workaround, see [KB318781](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=182995)."